# slick carousel - how to instantly jump to another slide during transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I want to be able to jump to the next slide instantly and without any further transition.

Currently this only works in between the transitions., but how to make it work during a transition? In other words I ideally need something like `$('.slick').slick("finishTransition")`

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps41xqh4/10).

```
<div class="slick">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
</div>
<a href="javascript:;" class='slick-next'>next</a>
```

```
$('.slick').slick({
                infinite: true,
                speed: 5000,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                centerMode: true,
                variableWidth: true,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 200,
                prevArrow: '',
                nextArrow: ''
});

$('.slick-next').click(function(){
    $('.slick').slick("slickSetOption", 'speed', 1, true)
    $('.slick').slick("slickNext")
    $('.slick').slick("slickSetOption", 'speed', 5000, true)
});
```

Comment: While I'm not familiar with the `slick` plugin, I'd assume that once you click next, `slick` fetches the transition speed once, and tells it to animate at that speed. Changing the speed *during* the animation won't do anything - it already retrieved the speed when the animation started. I believe what you're looking for is something similar to jQuery's `.finish()`.

Comment: I think you can use slickGoTo (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). You can get the next slide with slickCurrentSlide.

Comment: @Vincent does not work during transition. @ Santi yeah this is a good idea. But I tried `$('.slick').finish()` as well as `$('.slick-track').finish()` and it did not work. It seems like slick is using css transition but also a certain callback is fired after expected duration of transition which blocks every further action. That's why setting `$('.slick-track').css('transition', 'none')` works, but blocks all further slick action until expected end of transition. Is there a way to stop all slick action i wonder?

Comment: Not sure if I'm following the end goal, but something like this? I'm pausing the autoplay when you click the next button, then manually going to the next slide (with no transition), then restarting autoplay. https://jsfiddle.net/ps41xqh4/14/

Comment: Have you had any joy with this?

Answer (score 7):

After some digging I found an additional config option which should allow you to use the internal methods as you wish whilst animating.

```
waitForAnimate: false,
```

I've included your fiddle with this change only and it seems to provide the desired result.

It's documented on the projects github page: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/

You will probably need to experiment with how to make it performant, but this setting will ultimately free up the requests you make during animations.

https://jsfiddle.net/uhkagr7n/

The full config for reference:

```
$('.slick').slick({
  infinite: true,
  speed: 5000,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 200,
  prevArrow: '',
  nextArrow: '',
  waitForAnimate: false,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work. You have to dynamically disable the **waitForAnimate** option. And clearing setInterval's was needed as the autoplay was getting messed up. That might need some tweaking.

https://jsfiddle.net/ps41xqh4/47/

```
$('.slick').slick({
    infinite: true,
    speed: 5000,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 300,
    prevArrow: '',
    nextArrow: '',
    waitForAnimate: true
});

$('.slick-next').click(function(event) {
    for (i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
        window.clearInterval(i);
    }

    $('.slick').slick("slickSetOption", 'autoplay', false, true)
    $('.slick').slick("slickSetOption", 'speed', 1, true)
    $('.slick').slick("slickSetOption", 'waitForAnimate', false, false)
    $('.slick').slick("slickGoTo", $('.slick').slick('slickCurrentSlide'))
    $('.slick').one('afterChange', function(e, s, c) {
        $('.slick').slick("slickSetOption", 'speed', 5000, true)
        $('.slick').slick("slickSetOption", 'autoplay', true, true)
        $('.slick').slick("slickSetOption", 'waitForAnimate', true, false)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set the autoplay to false:

```
$('.slick').slick({
                infinite: true,
                speed: 5000,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                centerMode: true,
                variableWidth: true,
                autoplay: false,
                prevArrow: '',
                nextArrow: ''
});

$('.slick-next').click(function(){
    $('.slick').slick("slickSetOption", 'speed', 1, true)
    $('.slick').slick("slickNext")
    $('.slick').slick("slickSetOption", 'speed', 5000, true)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

after lots of head + wall banging, I've got a solution to this.

slick 1.8.1
jQuery 1.12.4

Basically you need to intercept the click event before Slick.js gets it, stopPropagation and preventDefault immediately using "true" on the click event handler, then pause, save the current settings, swap the settings and go to the next / prev slide, then reapply the original settings and start the autoplay again.

See below:

```
/* fast manual prev and next transitions */

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var direction;
  var classList = Array.from(event.target.classList);

  if ( classList.includes('slick-arrow') ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if ( classList.includes('slick-next') ) {
      direction = 'next';
    } else if ( classList.includes('slick-prev') ) {
      direction = 'prev';
    }
    slickManualChange(event, direction);
  }
  
}, true);

const slickManualChange = function(event, direction){

  var SSclasses = $(event.target).closest('[class*="your-class"]')[0].classList;
  var selector = '.' + Array.from(SSclasses).filter(classes => classes.includes('your-class'))[0];
  
  var autoplay = $(selector).slick("slickGetOption", 'autoplay');
  var speed = $(selector).slick("slickGetOption", 'speed');
  var waitForAnimate = $(selector).slick("slickGetOption", 'waitForAnimate');
  var useCSS = $(selector).slick("slickGetOption", 'useCSS');

  $(selector).slick("slickPause");

  $(selector).slick("slickSetOption", 'autoplay', false, true);
  $(selector).slick("slickSetOption", 'speed', 0, true);
  $(selector).slick("slickSetOption", 'waitForAnimate', false, true);
  $(selector).slick("slickSetOption", 'useCSS', false, true);
  
  if ( direction === 'next' ) {
    $(selector).slick("slickNext");
  } else if ( direction === 'prev' ) {
    $(selector).slick("slickPrev");
  }
  
  $(selector).slick("slickSetOption", 'autoplay', autoplay, true);
  $(selector).slick("slickSetOption", 'speed', speed, true);
  $(selector).slick("slickSetOption", 'waitForAnimate', waitForAnimate, false);
  $(selector).slick("slickSetOption", 'useCSS', useCSS, false);

  $(selector).slick("slickPlay");
}
```

You can simplify the selector if you always use the same one, but I use variants of a similar one for different slideshows on each page, and different pages.

Hope this helps.